# Twilio Worker in Task Router

Tags: ruby, twilio

I am building an application using twilio's Task Router. I followed the quickstart tutorial at https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/creating-a-priority-queue-for-your-call-centre-with-taskrouter.html.

I am able to get the task created. Assignment callback is also reaching the application. In the assignment callback response, I return the following JSON response,

```
{
"instruction": "dequeue"
"post_work_activity_sid": "WA157bdc5be67d91999de9fc68bb1d0f67"
}
```

The dequeue operation is not happening. I have double checked if I have assigned contact_uri for the worker. Still call is not reaching the worker. Menawhile, the portal says the worker is reserved. Eventually the call times out and the task gets marked as canceled.

My question is whether this ocurring because the worker's contact uri is another Twilio phone number I own. When I dial that contact uri , I am able to hear the "Say" response that I had preconfigured.

Does anybody have suggestion here?

Comment: It sounds to me like the request URL for the webhook for the worker's number is not working, especially if you cannot hear the Say response. Can you share the code that is powering that response? Or perhaps check in the Twilio Monitor for error alerts to see what is going on there?

Comment: @philnash Thanks for suggesting Twilio Monitor. Now I get a vague understanding of what is causing the problem.
Warning: 40133 - TaskRouter->Dequeue
{
    "code": 21215,
    "message": "Account not authorized to call +448000119447. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21215",
    "status": 400
}
I am not trying to call any international numbers. Just the same UK number we own. Any suggestions?

Comment: @philnash I have tried sending from and to parameter in assignment callback response. Still the twilio monitor shows me the same warning I posted above. 
My assignment callback response,
`{
instruction: "dequeue"
to: "+448008021447"
from: "+448000119416"
post_work_activity_sid: "WA157bdc5be67d91999de9fc68bb1d0f67"
}`